# Create a dataframe based on 2 dataframes for eligibility and ordering

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 input dataframes like so

eligibleDs

```
+---------+--------------------+
|      cid|        eligibleUIds|
+---------+--------------------+
|     1234|offer3,offer1,offer2|
|     2345|       offer1,offer3|
|     3456|       offer2,offer3|
|     4567|              offer2|
|     5678|                null|
+---------+--------------------+
```

suggestedDs

```
+---------+--------------------+
|      cid|       suggestedUids|
+---------+--------------------+
|     1234|offer2,offer1,offer3|
|     2345|offer1,offer2,offer3|
|     3456|offer1,offer3,offer2|
|     4567|offer3,offer1,offer2|
|     5678|offer1,offer2,offer3|
+---------+--------------------+
```

I want the output dataframe to be like so

outputDs

```
+---------+--------+
|      cid|  topUid|
+---------+--------+
|3456     |offer3  |
|5678     |null    |
|4567     |offer2  |
|1234     |offer2  |
|2345     |offer1  |
+---------+--------+
```

The idea being that

- First data frame is a list of uids(each corresponding to some content id) that a user is eligible to see
- Second data frame is a suggested order of uids to be shown for that user
- If, for an id, the top suggested uid is present in the uids that can be shown then show that uid else move down the suggested list till you get to an uid that can be shown
- Basically eligibleDs decides the presence and suggestedDs decides the order

I have been able to come up with something like this

```
val combinedDs = eligibleDs.join(suggestedDs, Seq("cid"), "left")
val outputDs = combinedDs.map(row => {
  val cid = row.getInt(0)
  val eligibleUids = row.getString(1)
  val suggestedUids = row.getString(2)
  val suggestedUidsList = suggestedUids.split(",")

  var topUid = ""
  import scala.util.control.Breaks._
  breakable {
    for(uid <- suggestedUidsList) {
      if(eligibleUids!=null && eligibleUids.contains(uid)) {
        topOffer = uid
        break
      }
    }
  }

  Out(cid, topUid)
})
```

This seems rather kludgy, can someone help let me know if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dropWhile` to drop unmatched items in the list in `suggestedUids` and `headOption` to check for the first item in the remaining list, here's a more idiomatic way for generating `outputDs`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

case class Out(cid: Int, topUid: String)

val outputDs = combinedDs.map{
  case Row(cid: Int, null, _) =>
    Out(cid, null)

  case Row(cid: Int, eligibleUids: String, suggestedUids: String) =>
    val topUid = suggestedUids.split(",").
      dropWhile(!eligibleUids.contains(_)).headOption match {
        case Some(uid) => uid
        case None      => null
      }
    Out(cid, topUid)
}

outputDs.show
// +----+------+
// | cid|topUid|
// +----+------+
// |1234|offer2|
// |2345|offer1|
// |3456|offer3|
// |4567|offer2|
// |5678|  null|
// +----+------+
```

Note that `combinedDs` as described in the question is a DataFrame.  Should it be converted to a Dataset, `case Row(...)` should be replaced with `case (...)`.

Comment: Answer has been slightly refactored to use `case` partial function for readability.